# Build arrays of objects with psql jsonb (allow dupes)

Tags: node.js, postgresql, jsonb

I'm attempting to build arrays of objects with psql jsonb functionality. This is the basic structure I'm aiming for:

```
{
  blue:
    [
      {
        id: "123abc",
        version: 2
      },
      {
        id: "432cba",
        version: 1
      }
    ],
  red:
    [
      {
        id: "456hyg",
        version: 1
      },
      ...
}
```

This is the psql I'm currently working with:

```
INSERT INTO game.settings (name, value)
VALUES ($1, json_build_object($6::varchar,
json_build_array(json_build_object($2::varchar, $3::varchar, $4::varchar, $5::int))))
ON CONFLICT (name) DO UPDATE SET value = settings.value::jsonb ||
json_build_object($6::varchar,
json_build_array(json_build_object($2::varchar, $3::varchar, $4::varchar, $5::int)))::jsonb
```

This works but do to my current `ON CONFLICT` logic only one object appears in each array. On conflict, the new object overwrites the old. How can I alter this to allow for multiple objects within each array no matter if their `id` and `version` already appear?

Comment: You have a problem with closing parenthesises.

Comment: @Abelisto, good catch, also needed `::jsonb` at the end.